# testing mobile apps at home (IIS hosted)

Tags: jquery-mobile, iis, razor, lan

I am not sure what to look for with the current problem and I appreciate your suggestions.

Basically, all I want to do is locally host a web application on IIS and access it from my mobile browser.

My web application is hosted on the local IIS and works fine on the main machine. I can use my computer name, internal ip or external ip instead of localhost to connect to the app from the main computer. But when I go to another computer (which I can see and exchange files with) connected to the same network I cannot access the web application on the main machine. I tried ip and machine name.

At work, we are connected to a Domain and I tried the same thing with the work computer. When I write my computer name or it's ip, I can access hosted app from another computer.

So the question is, do I have to have a domain for this capability and if so, Is it possible to create a local domain at a home network? What do I need to search for to get this working? Is WAMP a must?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently opening the outbound/inbound port 80 from windows firewall is enough